# "This is not a bootable device " after installing Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: grub2, 20.04, uefi, hp, grubrescue

[Ubuntu boot file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ifbk.jpg)
[Not a bootable device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vg3rX.jpg)
I'm Using HP notebook - 15-bs576tx.
I recently bought a wd ssd of 500gb SATA M2. I backed up everything that was on my 1TB HDD. Clean wiped everything and started to Install Ubuntu. Installation finished no issues there. But I'm not able to boot into Ubuntu directly. It shows "This is not a bootable device ..... Grub rescue"
But if i restart and change the boot device to "Boot from EFI file" and select the  "grubx64.efi" from the Ubuntu option shown in the EFI menu it boots up perfectly.
Is there any way to directly boot into Ubuntu rather than going into boot devices and changing these ?
PS: I have checked a lot of these questions on the internet , but i couldn't find any that helps. I tried almost every solution i found but nothing helps.

Comment: Are you dual booting with Windows? Many HPs are not dual boot or Linux friendly. Have you updated UEFI from HP? Some have said that helps, but update should be done anyway. If not dual booting you can change name/label of boot entry to "Windows Boot Manager" to make HP happy, but actually boot Ubuntu. Or boot fallback/hard drive entry as default. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win

Comment: Exact same problem, Fresh install on an entire disk (no dual boot) on a Desktop PC. Tries with the updated installer and the old one. Installed 3 times, no boot.

Comment: @oldfred I had dual boot on my old HDD which i formatted before the installation on the SSD.

Comment: Did you try the work around of creating a Windows description entry that boots using shimx64.efi per link above?

Comment: @oldfred Thank you but I tried a lot of solutions and finally i got it working. I don't know which one worked otherwise I would have added that link as an answer over here. Anyways thanks for your time.